# Any idiomatic expression in Russian commonly misinterpreted by non-Russian speakers?

Tags: idioms

Do you know of any idiomatic expression in Russian, the meaning or etymology of which is usually misinterpreted by non-Russian speakers? Is there such an expression in Russian that Russian speakers are already tired of explaining to foreigners that the meaning of it or its original meaning is not what they think.

One that comes to my mind is Nikita Khrushchev's "Мы покажем вам кузькину мать!" rendered by interpreters at the time as "We will bury you all!", which was not really what the expression really meant. Do you know of any other such cases?

(I guess it's a bit off-topic here - sorry about that)

Comment: I think most of idioms are usually misinterpreted by non-Russian speakers,
For example: Оказать медвежью услугу  or Переливать из пустого в порожнее

Comment: *мы вас похороним* and *мы вам покажем кузькину мать* were two different phrases in original Russian, said by Khruschev on two different occasions.

Comment: @Quassnoi - Were they rendered in English differently?

Comment: @rpc1 - Can you, please, give an example of how those two idioms usually are misinterpreted by non-Russian speakers?

Comment: @brilliant: of course they were.

Comment: @Quassnoi - Do you know how 'мы вам покажем кузькину мать' was rendered?

Comment: @brilliant: it was one of Khrushchev's favorite expressions, but most famously it was uttered during the kitchen debate with Richard Nixon. According to Victor Sukhodrev, it was translated literally that time.

Comment: About how Кузькина мать was translated- https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuzma%27s_mother